# Apply a ranking to a row of average values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ranking, worksheet-function

I already have a spreadsheet set up for 23 salespeople. Row 24 is their customer service index averages. So across the top in `B` through `X` I have the salespeople. Their total scores in Row 22 and their averages in Row 24. I would like to rank their average (descending order) in Row 24. Excluding zeros.

Here is what I have come up with (in B28):

```
=IF(B24=0,"",IF(B24="x",COUNTIFS(B$24:X$24,">"&X24,X$24:X$24,"<>0",B$24:X$24,"x")+1,""))
```

it won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a quadriplegic running my own business, and any help I can get to not have to add/multiply/subtract/ divide would be a great thing!

Comment: Two questions: (1) What version of Excel are you using?, and (2) Do you want to rank them in ascending or descending order?

Comment: Iron using Excel 2010, and I want to rank them in descending order

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
=IF(B24=0,"",RANK(B24,$B$24:$X$24))
```

and copy across to suit.

Comment: When I put this one in. I aM getting all zeros. When I checked the cell it copied all the way across just fine, but is not ranking them

Comment: I think I found the problem but don’t know how to fix it. Some columns have no scores entered so on the row 28 on some columns I have the #DIV/0!   Could this be my problem? If so, how can I fix it. Eventually something will be added in every row, but right now. Some have nothing entered.

Comment: That did not do it. I went in and entered a 1 in each salesperson and now row 28 just has all zeros

Comment: Bear with me. I am in idiot when it comes to Excel. I always get the DIV errors. How do I type a formula to remove them. I tried adding to my formula yours and it will not work. Just 2 lines down, I used this formula to average the stores and it works perfectly =RANK(B 30,$B30:$X30,0) A couple questions.
How do I get the DIV error not to work on this line? And why won’t this line work online 24 substituting the 30 for 24  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're Excel 2010 or newer you can use the `RANK.EQ()` function. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rank-eq-function-HP010335687.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010335659 for usage.

Assuming you want to rank then in a descending order (higher numbers rank first), you can use the following:

In **B28**:

```
=IF(B24=0,"",RANK.EQ(B24,$B$24:$X$24))
```

Then just copy across to **X28**.

Use`RANK()` if you're using Excel 2007 or older.

Referring to the use of `RANK()` in Excel 2010 or newer, the Microsoft documentation states the following:

> IMPORTANT   This function has been replaced with one or more new functions that may provide improved accuracy and whose names better reflect their usage. Although this function is still available for backward compatibility, you should consider using the new functions from now on, because this function may not be available in future versions of Excel.

Comment: No. However, according to the MS docs for `RANK()` it has only been retained for backwards compatibility. See [http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rank-function-HP010335659.aspx](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rank-function-HP010335659.aspx). I always suggest using newer functions when old ones have been replaced.

Comment: @pnuts understood, but if this question if found in the future, at a point in time when `RANK()` is no longer a viable answer, including the version caveat would be quite useful. if you believe my answer is too specific, please let me know and I will gracefully delete it.

Comment: I copied this formula put it in the cell and drag it across. All the cell formulas changed fine, but it still is just showing zeros all the way across the line. No rankings! excel 2010

Comment: I tried this one also  =RANK(B24,$B24:$X24,0)  is still coming up with all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I added more of the salespeople scores and had no more DIV/0 errors online 24 and low and behold, row 26 all filled in correctly. It was trying to calculate the 0 cells on line 24, in which there was 3 DIV/0, and they came up with a DIV/0 error all the way across row 26. Now if I can just figure out how to get it to put a 0 in their.